# how to display sql statements also in log file while executing the .sql file in shell script

Tags: sql, oracle, shell, unix, scripting

```
I am trying as below :

`$ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus -s >>$SQL_LOG_FILE /nolog <<EOF
connect $USER_NAME/$PASSWRD@$HOST_NAME
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT 1
set serveroutput on size unlimited
set echo on
spool myfile_log.log
@$SQL_FILE_DIR/$SQL_FILE
spool off;
EOF`
```

sql statements are executed and the output is displaying. But the sql statements are not getting inserted into log file. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You may need

```
set echo on
```

From [documentation:](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12040.htm#i2698923)

> SET ECHO {ON | OFF} Controls whether or not to echo commands in a
>   script that is executed with @, @@ or START. ON displays the commands
>   on screen. OFF suppresses the display. ECHO does not affect the
>   display of commands you enter interactively or redirect to SQL*Plus
>   from the operating system.